# Storing json array in SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: user and phone. The table phone has a reference to the table user. This allows several phone numbers for each user.

I am sending the information to the SQL server in json format, but I am struggeling to store the phone numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[phone](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [type] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [varchar](12) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @jsonVariable = N'{
   "name":"Joe Smith",
   "phones":[
      {
         "phone":"+1 123 123-4567",
         "type":"business"
      },
      {
         "phone":"+1 987 987-6543",
         "type":"mobile"
      }
   ]
}'

DECLARE @userId int
DECLARE @userName varchar(max) = (SELECT userName FROM OPENJSON (@jsonVariable) WITH (userName varchar(max) N'$.name'))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[user] ([name]) VALUES (@userName)

SET @userId = @@IDENTITY
```

The question now is: is there something like a "forEach" routine to store all phone numbers?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL 12.0 (Azure SQL Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OPENJSON to get all the records from the phones array in your json.

Try this as part of your existing code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[phone] (
                              [userId]
                            , [type]
                            , [phone]
                          )
            SELECT @userId
                 , [c].[type]
                 , [c].[phone]
            FROM   [dbo].[user] [a]
            INNER JOIN OPENJSON(@jsonVariable)
                       WITH (
                                [userName] VARCHAR(MAX) '$.name'
                              , [phones] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON --bring your phones array back out.
                            ) AS [b]
                ON [b].[userName] = [a].[name]
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([b].[phones]) --Cross apply to get all records. This will return all the records in phones for the specific user you have inserted in dbo.[user]
                       WITH (
                                [phone] NVARCHAR(12) '$.phone'
                              , [type] NVARCHAR(12) '$.type'
                            ) [c];
```